# Two Tests for Exactness

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, vector-fields, fake-proofs, line-integrals

Suppose we have a differential equation of the form $M(x,\ y)\ dx + N(x,\ y)\ dy = 0$, where $\frac{\partial N}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial M}{\partial y} \neq 0$.  It is thus inexact, and absent multiplication by an integrating factor, has no potential function.

We can write this equation as $\vec f(x,\ y)\cdot d\vec r = \vec 0\cdot d\vec r$, where $\vec f = \begin{bmatrix}M(x,\ y) \\ N(x,\ y)\end{bmatrix}$ and $\vec d\vec r = \begin{bmatrix}dx \\ dy\end{bmatrix}$, without altering the differential form.  Now let's take the closed line integral of both sides along an arbitrary curve, yielding $\oint\vec f\cdot d\vec r = \oint\vec 0\cdot d\vec r$.

Regardless of the curve, the RHS simplifies to $0$.  But then $\oint\vec f\cdot d\vec r = 0$, implying that $\vec f$ is conservative, and therefore should have a potential function, allowing us to solve the differential equation.  On the other hand, we assumed earlier that the scalar curl of $\vec f$ was nonzero, and therefore should have no potential function.  What is causing the apparent contradiction here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\vec f(x,\ y)\cdot d\vec r = 0$ is not an identity valid for all $x$, $y$, $dx$ and $dy$, it is only true on certain curves (the integral curves of the differential equation).  So you can't integrate this around an arbitrary curve and expect to get $0$.

Comment: It seems to me that if $M(x,\ y)\ dx + N(x,\ y)\ dy = 0$ holds for all $x$ and $y$, then $\vec f(x,\ y)\cdot d\vec r = 0$ must hold for all $x$ and $y$ as well, since this is just a reverse application of the dot product.

Comment: I should have said, valid for all $x, y, dx$ and $dy$ (edited).

Comment: Hmm, while this edit does make the geometry a bit more mysterious, I still think the step in question is clear, algebraically.  $\vec f(x,\ y)\cdot d\vec r$ is simply another way to notate the LHS of the equation $M(x,\ y)\ dx + N(x,\ y)\ dy = 0$.  Granted, the dot product is not injective, but if the LHS equals $0$, then surely $\vec f(x,\ y)\cdot d\vec r$ must as well.

Comment: The LHS is zero only in the direction of the vector field corresponding to the differential equation.